# python GeocoderError: Error REQUEST_DENIED

Tags: python, geocode

so it's like this:
I need to find a location of where a photo was taken.
I've managed to take the coordinate of the photo and save it in latitude and longitude variables but when I try to extract the city location of those coordinate via python i get that error:
my code :

```
import reverse_geocoder as rg 
from pygeocoder import Geocode
location = Geocoder.reverse_geocode(12.9716,77.5946)
print("City:",location.city)
```

the error :
GeocoderError: Error REQUEST_DENIED
Query: https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=12.971600%2C77.594600&sensor=false&bounds=&region=&language=

how do I resolve it ? if ill get a KPI code of google maps where do I insert it?

tnx for the help!

Comment: You did not set an API key. Please click on your posted link and read the JSON response. It includes a link how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your API key.
See an example below

```
import googlemaps

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='Add Your Key here')

# Look up an address with reverse geocoding
reverse_geocode_result = gmaps.reverse_geocode((40.714224, -73.961452))
```

Comment: thanks! 
It's kinda weird.
i did use the code and then I got a different error which said I don't have the library installed so I've installed it and now I'm back to the same error..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing usage of two reverse geocoder packages.

#### reverse_geocoder

The [reverse_geocoder](https://github.com/thampiman/reverse-geocoder) you are first importing will work just like this

```
In [1]: import reverse_geocoder as rg

In [2]: results = rg.search((12.9716,77.5946))
Loading formatted geocoded file...

In [3]: results
Out[3]:
[{'lat': '12.97194',
  'lon': '77.59369',
  'name': 'Bangalore',
  'admin1': 'Karnataka',
  'admin2': 'Bangalore Urban',
  'cc': 'IN'}]
```

The `reverse_geocoder` package is nice since it is an *offline* reverse geocoder, meaning that it has all the addresses included in the package, and it does not need any API keys or an internet access.

#### pygeocoder

The Geocoder from pygeocoder would need an API key for the Google Maps. See the [Google Maps API Key documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key) for instructions. Note that you'll need a billing account for Google Maps, and it using it may cost money.  The correct syntax would be

```
location = Geocoder(api_key='INSERT API KEY HERE').reverse_geocode(12.9716,77.5946)
```

The documentation for the `Geocoder` is, from IPython help:

```py
In [4]: Geocoder?
Init signature: Geocoder(api_key=None, client_id=None, private_key=None)
Docstring:      A Python wrapper for Google Geocoding V3's API
Init docstring:
Create a new :class:`Geocoder` object using the given `client_id` and
`private_key`.

:param api_key: Google Maps Simple API key
:type api_key: string

:param client_id: Google Maps Premier client ID
:type client_id: string

:param private_key: Google Maps Premier API key
:type client_id: string

Google Maps API Premier users can provide his key to make 100,000
requests a day vs the standard 2,500 requests a day without a key
```

Comment: yep, that was the problem. I tried to use  reverse_geocoder  as you explained and it worked. also, I understood that the pygeocoder didn't work because I don't have an API payment account so the API did not work.
the last question is where can I find further information about this library(  reverse_geocoder) can it show me the country of the coordinate or only the city?.

Comment: The `cc` in the output is [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) country code. If you want to convert it into full country name, take a look at [pycountry](https://github.com/flyingcircusio/pycountry), or this [iso3166-1.json](https://github.com/flyingcircusio/pycountry/blob/master/src/pycountry/databases/iso3166-1.json) file.

Answer (score 0):

also didnt work.
i tried :

```
location = Geocoder(api_key='myCode').reverse_geocode(12.9716,77.5946)
```

this is the entire error if it helps you to help me:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GeocoderError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-083207d98109> in <module>
     68 # print("City:",location.city)
     69 
---> 70 location = Geocoder(api_key='myCode').reverse_geocode(12.9716,77.5946)
     71 

D:\paython\lib\site-packages\pygeocoder.py in reverse_geocode(self, lat, lng, sensor, bounds, region, language)
    161 
    162         if self is not None:
--> 163             return GeocoderResult(self.get_data(params=params))
    164         else:
    165             return GeocoderResult(Geocoder.get_data(params=params))

D:\paython\lib\site-packages\pygeocoder.py in get_data(self, params)
    210 
    211         if response_json['status'] != GeocoderError.G_GEO_OK:
--> 212             raise GeocoderError(response_json['status'], response.url)
    213         return response_json['results']
    214 

GeocoderError: Error REQUEST_DENIED
Query: https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=12.971600%2C77.594600&sensor=false&bounds=&region=&language=&key=AIzaSyB7FWHM4cZsUogGIb50R3uTK2ks97jh6vM
```